# Manipulate object's property while in event handler

Tags: javascript, this

I've learned that for scope reasons the `this` keyword inside an event listener, which is embedded in an object, doesn't refer to the global object but rather to the element which triggered the event.

Now, I understand that if I want to fetch a property I can save it to a variable before the event handler is called. But what can I do if I want to manipulate the property's value?

In the following piece of code I am trying to manipulate the `drugCount` property within the `removeDrug` event listener.

```
var Drugs = {

    drugs: $("#drugs_table"),
    drugRow: $("#drug").html(),
    drugCount: 0,

    init: function() {
      this.addDrugRow();
      this.removeDrugRowHandler();
    },

    addDrugRow: function() {
     this.drugCount++;
     this.drugs.append(this.drugRow.replace(/{{id}}/,this.drugCount));
     $(".drugsSelect").select2();
    },

    removeDrugRowHandler: function() {

    drugCount = this.drugCount; 
     // also a problematic solution, because it only retains the inital drugCount. 
     // i.e I need a way to access the "live" count from within the event

        $(document).on("click",".removeDrug",function(){
            if (drugCount>0) {

                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                this.drugCount--; // how should I approach this?
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
var Drugs = function() {

    var me = this;

    me.drugs = $("#drugs_table");
    me.drugRow = $("#drug").html();
    me.drugCount = 0;

    me.init = function() {
          this.addDrugRow();
          this.removeDrugRowHandler();
    };

    me.addDrugRow = function() {
         this.drugCount++;
         this.drugs.append(this.drugRow.replace(/{{id}}/,this.drugCount));
         $(".drugsSelect").select2();
    };

    me.removeDrugRowHandler= function() {

        var drugCount = me.drugCount;

        $(document).on("click",".removeDrug",function(){
            if (drugCount>0) {

                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                me.drugCount--;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the easy solution is to use the object name instead of the contextual `this`.
So instead of `this.drugCount` I used `Drugs.drugCount`.

However, this solution only works if I am in the context of a single object. If I were to write a "class" (i.e `var Drugs = function(){ ... }`) this won't work.